# htaccess redirect to another site keeping the same URL

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to use htaccess to redirect a site to another site (hosted on the same Virtualmin server)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://sub.domain2.co.uk$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

This code is just giving a 500 Internal Server Error.

In the error logs, I can see:

```
[Tue Jul 09 18:00:29.276394 2019] [ssl:error] [pid 17001] [remote 104.26.6.131:443] AH01961: SSL Proxy requested for sub.domain2.co.uk:80 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]
[Tue Jul 09 18:00:29.276436 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 17001] AH00961: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for 104.26.6.131:443 (sub.domain2.co.uk)
```

(I've changed the domains above to generic for privacy, but they match the two in my htaccess example)

I've also checked the apache config, and ssl engine is ON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say what is wrong, but here is a slightly modified version of your attempt that prevents some issues:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://sub.domain2.co.uk/$1 [P]
```

An alternative would be to use the proxy module directly, without the rewriting module:

```
ProxyPass / https://sub.domain2.co.uk/
ProxyPassReverse / https://sub.domain2.co.uk/
```

The entry in the error log file indicates that you have an issue with the ssl certificate on that proxied page... Could it be that the certificate does *not* match the host name you use in the target of your proxy rule?